# Highcharts stick column to x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Why are the columns in the demo code handing above the x axis. How do I make them stick to x axis.

Look at the https://jsfiddle.net/nmLo2sbu/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
         type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],

        lineColor: '#FF0000',
                offset:0,

    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
              minPointLength: 3,
           // stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts are not able to calculate extremes on yAxis, so tick 0 is placed in the middle. Additionally, the default value in `column` series for `threshold` is 0. You can force to calculate extremes for example by using `softMax` property.

```
yAxis: {
  ...,
  softMax: 1
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/08ohe6m3/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.threshold

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.softMax